# custom 404 page for missing object in s3 temporary signed URL

Tags: amazon-s3, http-status-code-404

I am generating some signed URL's for some private information in Amazon S3

In the case that the signed link has expired, or that the object doesn't exist there is an XML error that is reported, along with a 404 error (or 403 forbidden).

Is it possible to redirect the signed link 404 to a custom error page? This seems different to the 404 error page for the S3 static website settings.

My research so far has indicated that if you use the static pages, the permissions have to be publicly readable for all content and you cannot generate the signed URL (or I'm doing it wrong) OR if you use a signed URL the 404 error doesn't redirect and you just get the XML error.

all the links i have found point to use the static pages but I don't think that applies in this case.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible that what you want is this: 
In the [Developer guide](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?WebsiteHosting.html) there is a paragraph about "Custom Error Document Support" where I read the following sentence.

> You can optionally provide a custom error document with a
>   user-friendly error message and with additional help. You provide this
>   custom error document as part of adding website configuration to your
>   bucket. Amazon S3 returns your custom error document for only the HTTP
>   4XX class of error codes.

Comment: This only works if the presigned url is for an S3 web site.