# make url link to other url

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have an application where users can upload certain digital goods. Other users can purchase these, in which case a download link is presented right after, along with an email containing same link is sent. This link should expire after 7 days

Right now, when users upload their item, it is uploaded to S3 and the URL is stored on the Items collection.

Problem is, I don't want to give customers this direct link, as then I would have no way of expiring it. Instead, I want to create a new url that refers to the original S3 url when a purchase is made, and then send the customer this link instead

I figured I could make some sort of url shortener functionality that does this, but not sure if this is the most effective

Any idea how to accomplish this without leaking the original?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to have your application manage the 'read policy' for the s3 Object = the file people can download.  You can set the expiration for the policy.

In my meteor application, I'm using this library : 
https://github.com/arbitrarytech/s3policy

on the server :

```
Meteor.methods({

  get_s3_read_policy: function(_key,_filename) {

    var SECONDS_BEFORE_TIMEOUT = 1000;
    var s3 = new s3Policies( CONFIG.aws_access_key , CONFIG.aws_secret_access_key );
    var signedURL = s3.readPolicy( _key, 'your_bucket_name' , SECONDS_BEFORE_TIMEOUT , _filename); 
    return signedURL;
  }

});
```

In your case maybe all you need is the signed URL.  In my app on the client this is how I'm starting the download.

```
  Meteor.call('get_s3_read_policy', key, filename , function(err,_signedURL) {

    if (err){
        console.log("Error retrieving the signed url for download ", err);
    }else{
      window.open(_signedURL,"_self"); 
    }
  });
```

So, I think it would be possible to email the user this signed URL directly, then if it expires the user will see an error and not be able to access the resource.  I read there is even a way in s3 to present the user with a nice error page [custom 404 page for missing object in s3 temporary signed URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329130/custom-404-page-for-missing-object-in-s3-temporary-signed-url) but i haven't tried it.

Answer (score 1):

Any URL that references another URL can be discovered by a client, that's the point of HTTP: allow a client to navigate resources and know their current location or state. If you provide an intermediary, it could pipe the real URL content to the client, and you could control visibility and lifetime because the client will never actually talk to the resource directly. You could easily accomplish this by writing middleware that hashes the real URL or simply provides a key to it and subsequently provides a new URL to the client that references the intermediary.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I am interpreting the question correctly but maybe you can just use something like TinyURL API?

http://www.tiny-url.info/open_api.html

(Example from website)

```
$lurl = $_POST['long_url'];

$curl = curl_init(); 
$post_data = array('format' => 'json',
                   'apikey' => 'YOUR_API_KEY',
                   'provider' => 'PROVIDER_STRING',
                   'url' => $lurl );
$api_url = 'http://tiny-url.info/api/v1/create';
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

echo $result;
```

Another way is to just programmatically have a redirect link? That would differ based on what backend you use but could look something like the following:

```
For the route xxxx/<account/digitalgood_id>/<date>: 
  if date is older than a week: 
     say it is expired
  otherwise: 
     redirect to page/<account/digitalgood_id> which accesses to the S3 info
```